# InvalidCastException on identical types? (yes, Context... identical Contexts?)

Tags: c#, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset, .net

I have a strongly-typed `DataTable` on which I'm calling `GetChanges`:

```
myApples.CropTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted)
```

I want to access the results of this using my strongly-typed `CropTable` and `CropRow` classes. So I tried casting the results, like this:

```
(AppleDataSet.CropDataTable)myApples.CropDataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted)
```

*DOINGGGG*, InvalidCastException:

> [A]CropDataTable cannot be cast to [B]CropDataTable. Type A originates from 
>   'FarmingBO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=acbff80904caf0cb' 
>   in the context 'Default' at location 
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\Farming\3b503e68\8f2b701b\assembly\dl3\8d20c3b3\a16c5196_27eacc01\FarmingBO.DLL'. 
>   Type B originates from 
>   'FarmingBO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=acbff80904caf0cb' 
>   in the context 'Default' at location 
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\Farming\3b503e68\8f2b701b\assembly\dl3\8d20c3b3\a16c5196_27eacc01\FarmingBO.DLL'.

Is it just me, or are these types perfectly identical?

Comment: Try to write the output of Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies() to console to see if there is anything suspicious.

Comment: Try a Clean Solution and rebuild. Also try clearing out Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: I'd note that the error doesn't seem to include the namespace for the type, only the final type name (or have you edited this). Is it possible that, within the same assembly, you use the same type name in two different namespaces?

Comment: The actual failure was happening in my coworker's code. He suddenly said, "oh! I know what the problem is," and then went to his own workstation and fixed it. I'm going to try to get him to tell me what the problem was, but he probably won't answer until we get past next build.

Comment: @sq33G did you get the answer from your coworker? I'm facing the same thing...

Comment: @RobertIvanc No, he never told me. :( Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

If your strongly-typed table doesn't overload the `GetChanges` method it will not return a `CropDataTable` but the base `DataTable` instead.

The only way to get a strongly-typed `CropDataTable` is to copy all rows from the returned `DataTable`